# I am getting this error while installing blacklight project in ruby on rails for the bundle install in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: blacklight

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /tmp/bundler20170529-7305-1ybn2iijson-1.8.6/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170529-7305-1qu2mp6.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20170529-7305-1ybn2iijson-1.8.6/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20170529-7305-1ybn2iijson-1.8.6/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking!  Do you have the ruby-dev package installed?  You can get it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```